# Why do the eigen vectors corresponding to covariance matrix give principal component axes?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I request an explanation for this question. When I asked this in [physicsforums](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=4474547#post4474547) one person told me that it is a definition. I was just asking for how to prove the orthogonal eigen vectors obtained from covariance matrix (of course symmetric) form the principal component axes. How can such a thing be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the principal components of a matrix $X$ are given by forming its singular value decomposition $X = U \Sigma V^{\ast}$, in which case the principal components correspond to the action of $X$ on the columns of $V$, namely $v_i \mapsto \sigma_i u_i$. The $n$th principal component thus corresponds to the $n$th singular value paired with the $n$th left and right singular vectors (when they are ordered by descending magnitude).

When $X$ is a covariance matrix, then $X$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, and hence its eigenvalue decomposition is precisely its SVD.

Comment: Christopher A. Wong: Thanks for the reply. Which is the best reference or link which you know in this matter.

Comment: I can't think of one off the top of my head, but any book on matrix analysis and which covers the singular value decomposition should mention that it is the same as principal component analysis. The SVD is the mathematicians' name for it; PCA is the scientists' name.

Comment: thanks Christopher A. Wong